When is a postdoc "too long"?
Consider the following background information. The field is natural sciences. The goal is professorship/tenure. The country is Germany. It has been exactly two years since the completion of PhD at a different German institute. The plan is to move to the industry if the goal is not achieved within 5-6 years after the PhD.
Currently, the postdoc is actively applying (without success so far) for programs like Emmy Noether, DFG, BMBF, etc., including other third-party funding agencies. They most often state they are looking for people with experience abroad. None currently exists. Due to personal reasons, it is very difficult to do a postdoc in North America (abroad) to become the 'ideal candidate' for such programs.
Also, the postdoc supervises (unofficially) 3-4 PhD students full-time and manages other group-related affairs in the absence of the group leader. The group leader will not be able to supervise these students without the postdoc. Therefore, the group leader's interest is to keep the postdoc, she cannot guarantee tenure but has promised to 'help' (but nothing concrete). She has offered to extend the postdoc contract to a total of 5 years.
Question:
At what point in time does staying at this institute become detrimental to the goal of achieving tenure?

I find it distracting to write in this odd, detached, third-person style.

This question implies that only postdocs in North America would be considered "abroad" by the system? Are those same personal reasons preventing the postdoc from seeking another postdoc in close-by European countries, for example in Austria or the Netherlands? Considering decent train connections in Europe, and the lack of border control in the Schengen zone, the postdoc may even be able to find something close to the German border and continue residing in Germany in exchange for a slightly longer commute. Or is that also not an option for this person due to personal reasons?

Is this about the same person as you other question? Because this sounds increasingly like the position is not in the best interest of said person, regardless of duration.

Staying in Europe is possible. @MisterMiyagi yes

The postdoc is too long when you give up other, better, options. Or when you turn them down. There is no clock, though there may be firm time limits for postdocs. Times are hard in many places and many fields in academia.
Note, however, that people will start to wonder about you if you spend too much time in one or more postdocs. This may be unfair, but it happens.
If the person is actively seeking better options, by their own standard, then that is all they can do. They don't need to be the "ideal" candidate for any position, just good enough and equal to or better than the competition at the moment. And they need to use the postdoc to improve their chances by writing papers and collaborative work and such. Make sure that the activities of the postdoc enhance your own reputation and CV, not just that of the PI.
Note that the supervisor shouldn't be an obstacle, and there is no reason that future collaboration is impossible if the person gets a  position elsewhere. If they are an obstacle, then that needs to be discussed and a solution found. Hard and dependent on personalities and an expectation of ethical behavior that isn't always present. If they can't guarantee a future, then they need to spend effort of help the person move on.
But there is no optimum for any of your questions. No easy answers. No magic cookie. Keep looking, carefully evaluate options.
A postdoc is meant to be a stepping stone to a career, not a career itself. It can be helpful to a person when the time to publication of papers, perhaps based on the dissertation, is long. But effort to move beyond it is required throughout.
Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good.

Generally I agree. However, I think the way it works in Germany at the moment there is no denying that missing international experience is a disadvantage for tenure applications. Such jobs are hard to get, and you would have to make up your 'deficiencies' by some other achievement, such as a top publication record or some major scientific breakthrough.

Like the previous commenter, I generally agree with this answer, but I disagree with the statement that "there is no clock". There is a clock, which starts ticking the second you finish your PhD.  There is no set expiration date, but the longer it has been since the completion of your PhD, the harder it is to get your foot in the door. This can be ameliorated to some extent by having a strong research / publication record, but people are going to what's wrong with a candidate who is 6 years out form their doctorate and still in a postdoc position. (This is a US-centric perspective, however.)

@XanderHenderson I agree and would add that the clock is specific to location. Some places in the US do not have a clock but, I know some places do have a clock. For example, the U of Minnesota limits postdocs to 5 years if I recall correctly. Other places can have or not have their own clocks.

@RichardErickson Oh, that is actually a different point from the one I was making (but a very good point, nevertheless).  I was more thinking about how hiring committees look at long postdocs.  Generally speaking, the longer it has been since phd conferral, the more scrutiny an applicant is going to get by a hiring committee.

@RichardErickson, I assume that is the maximum length of any postdoc there. The absolute deadline after which you are no longer employable anywhere is a completely different concept. That was behind my "no clock" phrasing. No drop dead date for your career. It depends on what you accomplish. But as we all have noted, people start to ask questions.

@Buffy, actually there is a practical limit in Germany for being employable as a postdoc. After 6 years employment as a postdoc, it becomes very hard to be employed in a non-permanent position, and permanent positions are rare.  Details are here (in German): https://www.bmbf.de/DE/Forschung/Wissenschaftssystem/WissenschaftlicheKarriere/Wissenschaftszeitvertragsgesetz/wissenschaftszeitvertragsgesetz_node.html

@Snijderfrey, I'd guess the OP wants a career, not a non-permanent position. They specify professorship/tenure. And, again, it gets harder the longer you go for a variety of reasons.

Germany requires that researchers go into permanent positions after, IIRC, 12 years of temporary contracts. This imposes a necessary limit on the postdoc period for people who do not travel overseas for experience.

As I was finishing my PhD, a good friend gave me advice about postdoc duration. He said that a postdoc will likely continue to be useful to their host institution for much longer than they will be useful to the postdoc - and judging by your description of the postdoc's situation, this seems to hold true for this person as well. As Buffy's answer suggests, the goal of a postdoc is to continually improve and enhance one's profile and CV, in order to be better suited to the positions they are targeting.
He did put a timer on it - he suggested two years in any single postdoc will likely be the point when the returns from the positions diminish sufficiently that it may be better to move into a different position (even if just a postdoc). Since the focus of my research slightly shifted from my PhD to my postdoc, I set my own limit to 3 years rather than two. I then promptly ignored both his original advice and my revised version, stayed for four years, and then got a permanent academic post at the same University (while he made a career change and went to industry; can't remember if by choice or not). So this time limit is by no means set in stone.
Nonetheless, when I am advising postdocs now in my current permanent post, I do tell them that staying too long in any one postdoc will start raising eyebrows after a few years. I also tell them that I consider this unfair, as I understand there are likely family and other personal considerations, and that I hope that the number of academics sharing my opinions is slowly increasing. I strongly disagree with my colleagues that try their hardest to keep any outstanding postdoc we might have - I think this is selfish and only benefits the groups research, but not the postdoc in question.
Finally, consider what qualities are demonstrated by holding a position abroad at some point when applying for academic positions. Certainly, the ability to board a plane, get by in an environment that speaks a different language, or being familiar with diverse architecture styles, are not the qualities that any interview panel is interested in. Having the ability to collaborate within different research groups that likely practice different research styles, the ability to create your own research line while exploring a wide range of applications, and familiarity with different organisational structures that research departments may come in, are much more important.
So, taking all of this into account, consider how this postdoc can build their profile to demonstrate as many of these qualities as they can. Taking up a different postdoc position, even in Germany, will certainly demonstrate that the postdoc can collaborate with a wider profile of academics than staying in the same postdoc for 4-5 years. If even a move within Germany is not something this postdoc would consider due to personal reasons, they may consider compensating thru establishing strong international collaborations - they might achieve this by initiating research with any departmental academic guests that pass by their department, or attending more conferences and engaging academics in that way. It is likely that establishing collaborations in this way would be more challenging than if this person took a postdoc position elsewhere, but they might be prepared to accept this trade off considering their personal reasons. Or they may attempt to do short-term, week-long visits to departments and Universities abroad (considering that their current lab is benefitting greatly from this postdoc supervising PhD students, maybe this is a benefit they could negotiate with their current advisor). If their personal reasons allow them to be a bit more flexible, just not as flexible as to look for a position in North America, they may consider looking for postdoc positions elsewhere in Europe - this would likely be less of an administrative hussle if the postdoc is an EU citizen. Considering decent train connections in Europe, especially between bigger cities, as well as an increasing practice of remote working for several days a week, the person might even be able to stay living in Germany while holding a postdoc position abroad. Finally, consider that the idea of a footloose and fancy free postdoc who is free to gallivant all over the world for the sake of academic betterment is a fairly old one, and rapidly changing in modern times. Therefore, this person may have better luck applying for permanent/tenure-track positions in departments that are on average younger and staffed by younger academics - as they are more likely to share my opinion that collaborative qualities demonstrated by a candidate are more important than demonstrating those qualities thru international experience.
